# ¿ Cómo puedo hacer que mi iMac reconozca la versión 3.8 de python y no la 2.7?

Tags: python

Les pongo en antecedentes; yo trabajo con ordenadores de Apple. Tengo reinstalada la versión de python 2.7 y a su vez, he instalado python 3.8. Reseñar que yo uso como editor PyCharm que funciona con python 3.8.

El problema vienen cuando quiero instalar alguna Liberia que me reconoce sólo python 2.7 y no me deja instalar.

Lo que necesito es que mi iMac reconozca la última versión, no la antigua..

Comment: Si pones `python3` en lugar de `python` usarás la nueva. Te recomiendo crear entornos virtuales con el comando `python3 -m venv ~/venvs/nombre` (previamente creada la carpeta `~/venvs`) Y luego lo "activas" poniendo `source ~/venvs/nombre/bin/activate`. A partir de aqui todo lo que instales con `pip` va a ese entorno (carpeta) y no entra en conflicto con otras instalaciones. El entorno se desactiva al cerrar la terminal, recuerda activarlo de nuevo cada vez que crees una nueva terminal/pestaña.

Comment: ¿Existe algún método que se pueda desinstalar la versión 2.7 y dejar ya instalada la 3.8 y que el sistema la reconozca como predefinida?. La solución que me propones, estaría bien si sólo trabajase con la terminal, pero suelo trabajar con editor...

Comment: **No!!** OSX requiere python 2.8 para sus cosas. Si lo intentas desinstalar pueden dejar de funcionar correctamente herramientas del sistema. Por lo mismo tampoco se recomienda mucho andar instalando paquetes en el python del sistema, y es preferible siempre usar entornos virtuales como expliqué en el otro comentario

Comment: Si el editor con que trabajas es VSCode o PyCharm (ambos altamente recomendables!) están preparados para trabajar con entornos virtuales. Detectan automáticamente los que hayas creado en `~/venvs` y te dejan elegir cuál usar.

Comment: Perdona por mi desconocimiento, pero para realizar el entorno virtual voy a necesitar que me guíes. Entiendo que 1º hay que crear( ~/venvs ). Soy bastante novato, y no sé dónde ni cómo crearla.

Comment: He comprobado que se puede crear el entorno virtual a través de PyCharm. Dado que tengo pocos conocimientos, ¿me recomiendas que realice el entorno por el editor, y después instale los paquetes necesarios para conectar python con MSQL?

Comment: Si te apañas mejor haciéndolo a través del editor, pues hazlo así. Yo con PyCharm no tengo experiencia (uso VSCode) pero entiendo que al igual que te permite crear entornos virtuales, te permitirá activarlos e instalar paquetes en ellos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Al final he podido resolver mi problema. Cree una conda en PyCharm, luego instale la librería. 
Aún así, me daba error cuando intentaba acceder a mi base de datos. Así que investigando encontré una forma para reparar el error.